# If a compact set's boundary is the finite union of smooth Jordan curves, is it a domain?

Tags: general-topology

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact set such that it's boundary is a finite union of piecewise smooth Jordan curves.

For example:

[image: taken from wikipedia]

**Does this imply that $V \setminus \partial V$ is a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_%28mathematical_analysis%29)?**

*(If yes, does this also apply to higher finite dimensions, namely $\mathbb{R}^n$?)*

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to @UmbertoP it is clear that the answer is **no**, and a simple counter-example is the union of two disjoint closed disks.

Now, if I add the following conditions:

- The jordan curves mentioned are pairwise disjoint (Thanks @LeeMosher)
- One of the jordan curves is the boundary of a set that contains all other jordan curves

Do I have a domain now?

Comment: Do you intend, as your picture suggests, that the Jordan curves forming this union are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: What happens if $V$ is a union of two disjoint closed disks?

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for pointing that out, yes I want that. I was indeed feeling that some more conditions would be necessary.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you!! I don't know how I missed that. If I add the condition that one of the jordan curves fully encloses all the others, is it sufficient now, or still lacking other conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if one of the Jordan curves fully encloses all the others, you get counterexamples: Insert a closed disk in one the holes.

Let us first consider a non-connected $V$. If it has two or more components having an interior point, then $V \backslash \partial V$ cannot be connected. Hence $V$ must be required to have at most one component with an interior point. In this case all other components must be Jordan curves.

This shows that we may focus to *connected* $V$ having an interior point. In this case $V \backslash \partial V$ is clearly connected because $V$ is a $2$-manifold with boundary (in general not a smooth manifold since the Jordan curves are only piecewise smooth). Its interior is connected. See [Is the interior of a smooth manifold with boundary connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2107145) (the proof given in the first answer is valid also for topological manifolds).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for taking the time to answer a question that is over two years old! :)